# H264 NAL unit prefixes

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, rtp, video-encoding

I need some clarification on H264 NAL unit delimiter prefixes (`00 00 00 01` and `00 00 01`), I am using Intel Media SDK to generate a H264 and pack it into RTP. The issue is that so far I was looking only for `00 00 00 01` as a unit separator and basically was able to find only AUD,SPS,PPS and SEI units in the bitstream. Looking at the memory I saw that after the SEI there was a byte sequence `00 00 01 25` that could be a start of an IDR unit, but my search algorithm did not detect it because of a missing zero byte. Can anyone clarify the difference between `00 00 00 01` and `00 00 01` prefixes? Looking at [Chromium code](http://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/1312/src/media/filters/h264_to_annex_b_bitstream_converter.cc) it seems that first unit as well as AUD, SPS, PPS, and SEI have an extra zero:

```
if (first_nal_in_this_access_unit ||
    IsAccessUnitBoundaryNal(nal_unit_type)) {
    output_size += 1;  // Extra zero_byte for these nal units
    first_nal_in_this_access_unit = false;
}

...

static bool IsAccessUnitBoundaryNal(int nal_unit_type) {
    // Check if this packet marks access unit boundary by checking the
    // packet type.
    if (nal_unit_type == 6 ||  // Supplemental enhancement information
        nal_unit_type == 7 ||  // Picture parameter set
        nal_unit_type == 8 ||  // Sequence parameter set
        nal_unit_type == 9 ||  // Access unit delimiter
        (nal_unit_type >= 14 && nal_unit_type <= 18)) {  // Reserved types
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

1) I would assume I should look for both prefixes, but then I understand that I need to check the type of the next NAL unit in order to know the length of the current one (to know if the the prefix is 3 or 4 bytes and not consume a zero byte that could be an end of a previous NAL unit as the prefix).

2) Are PPS, SPS, and SEI sizes fixed? If so I could just jump to the end of the unit when looking for the next prefix.

I hope that someone who has had more experience with this can comment on the questions above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [H.264 spec](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264), B.1.2 Byte stream NAL unit semantics:

[image]

> zero_byte is a single byte equal to 0x00.
>
> When any of the following conditions are fulfilled, the zero_byte syntax element shall be present.
>
> - the nal_unit_type within the nal_unit( ) is equal to 7 (sequence parameter set) or 8 (picture parameter set)
> - the byte stream NAL unit syntax structure contains the first NAL unit of an access unit in decoding order, as specified by subclause 7.4.1.2.3.