# How can I parse stream video (byte array, H264) to ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, arrays, video

I develop application for android that shows stream video received from video server. It takes video from IP-cameras, codes them with libav codec to byte array and passes result byte array as stream to clients.

MediaCodec can't do this. I've searching for it, the question was [asked there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229871/is-it-possible-to-feed-mediacodec-bytearray-received-by-server-and-show-them-on)

, but no result.

Any ideas how to use ExoPlayer for this task?

Comment: It depends on how the encoder was configured. Is the stream wrapped in a container (like TS) or is is straight annex-b? Or is it something propriety?

Comment: Out data without container

Comment: hey have u found any solution